# installing Oracle 12c client

Tags: windows-10, oracleclient

I am trying to install Oracle 12c client on my development box running Windows 10 and it doesn't even start.

I downloaded the files from Oracle download web site, ran setup.exe and it flashes briefly and nothing happens. I made sure latest JRE and JDK are installed.

I have spent most of the day googling but most deal with errors that occur during installation whereas I can't even start the installation! No errors, no messages. Checked GAC on off chance DLLs might be there but they are not.

I have used the same set of files on other machines and servers (Windows 2008r2 and 2012r2) without any issues but can seem to be able to troubleshoot this one. Any ideas to put me on the right path is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a couple of days trying to figure out the issue, uninstalling/reinstalling JRE and JDK and all that, the issue turned out to be the hard drive size. Apparently max dive size where you install the client is 2TB and mine was 3TB. I had to shrink the drive and it worked after that. Hopefully it saves someone some pain.

A couple of links for more info.

[Installing on large disk](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36834/disks-2.html)

[Oracle Universal Installer](http://codentonic.net/2013/03/12/oracle-universal-installer/)